# How can I clone a git repo from an LINUX AMI instance

Tags: git, amazon-web-services, amazon-ami

I crated a git-server and I created a bare repo in my AWS instance, but when I tried to clone to my local computer I got this error.

```
git clone git_user1@AWS_IP:medicel_repo .
Cloning into '.'...
Load key "/Path/to/.ssh/medicel_aws_git.pub": Permission denied
git_user1@AWS_IP: Permission denied (publickey).
fatal: Could not read from remote repository.

Please make sure you have the correct access rights
and the repository exists.
```

https://i.stack.imgur.com/Z2XzP.png

Comment: Have you checked where what you did differs from the doc you followed? link the doc you followed.

Comment: A "Permission denied" error means that the server rejected your connection. Try this  to debug your key problem. https://help.github.com/en/github/authenticating-to-github/error-permission-denied-publickey

Comment: Thanks to reply, I follow this https://adhoctuts.com/setup-remote-git-repository-server-on-centos-7/